# MDB for receiving emails

Tags: email, jakarta-ee, jboss, message-driven-bean, wildfly

I'm trying to receive emails with a message-driven bean. I'm using jboss wildfly. Unfortunatley, I can't find a real documentation on it. This is the most I've found so far:

```
@MessageDriven(activationConfig={
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName="mailServer", propertyValue="imap.gmail.com"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName="mailFolder", propertyValue="INBOX"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName="storeProtocol", propertyValue="imap"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName="userName", propertyValue="me@gmail.com"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName="password", propertyValue="xxx")
    })
@ResourceAdapter("mail-ra.rar")
public class EMailReceiver implements MailListener {


    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message msg) {

        System.out.println("MSG: " + msg.toString());
    }

}
```

I have several questions on how to make this work. Sorry for putting them all into one question, but I believe they belong together.

1. what is this ResourceAdapter? I can find a ResourceAdapter class, but not an annotation.
2. where do I get the correct mail-ra.rar and where do I put it ? I asssume this might come in different versions and I can't find one inside wildfly.
3. is the annotation config sufficient or do I need to configure anything in xml?

Comment: `mail-ra.rar` is provided by the IronJacamar project. There's a [forum post](https://community.jboss.org/message/725319) for AS7 that might help with Wildfly, too. Tbh, after looking a few minutes at the provided documentation I got scared and ran back to the safety of my Timer based EJBs. Since you use gmail as an example, I think you spare yourself a ton of work if you poll (using a timer service) instead of reacting to messages (which are going to be generated by a polling service, anyway).

Comment: thanks. I guess I'll go the timer route as well then. The MDB looked tempting as it looked like an out-of-the-box solution. But I guess it isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm no expert in IronJacamar, which is what you'd need to get configured for an [inbound adapter](http://www.ironjacamar.org/doc/userguide/1.2/en-US/html/ch01.html#overview_inbound). My impression from reading the docs is that there are several layers of abstraction hiding a simple polling of the gmail IMAP service.

Good news is: you can do this <strike>easily</strike> yourself.

You have to configure a mail [Session](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/mail/Session.html). I've ripped the following extract for `standalone.xml` from a [Wildfly example](https://github.com/wildfly/quickstart/tree/master/mail):

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:mail:1.0">
<mail-session jndi-name="java:/jboss/mail/MyGmail">
    <imap-server address="example.com" port="432">
        <login name="nobody" password="pass"/>
    </imap-server>
</mail-session>
</subsystem>
```

If you've set it up like this, you can refer to your session as a `Resource`:

```
@Stateless
public class PollingImapAccess {
    @Resource(name = "java:/jboss/mail/MyGmail")
    private Session session;

    @Schedule(hour = "*")
    public void init() {
        try {
            IMAPStore store = (IMAPStore) session.getStore();
            if (!store.isConnected()) store.connect();
            // grab your folders, scan for new messages     
        } catch (MessagingException ex) { /* handle exception */ }
    }
}
```

This would cause the EJB container to wake up your bean every hour and connect to your gmail account. You can read more about timers in the [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/ejb-basicexamples004.htm#BNBOY).

I don't really appreciate that you have to burden your generic server config with your personal account information, you can fall back to the [Session#getInstance() method](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/mail/Session.html#getInstance%28java.util.Properties%29):

```
Properties gmail = new Properties();
gmail.setProperty("mail.imaps.host", "imap.gmail.com");
gmail.setProperty("mail.imaps.port", "993");

Session session = Session.getInstance(gmail);
IMAPSSLStore mystore = (IMAPSSLstore) session.connect("me@gmail.com", "xxx");
```

The full list of settable properties is available in the [javadoc](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/com/sun/mail/imap/package-summary.html).

In this case you don't need the `@Resource` at all and can just wire up a new connection every time the method wakes up. Note that if plan to have any significant load on there, you probably want to cache that store object and only connect if the connection timed out.

Comment: yes, that's what I'm doing now. the current config for wildfly is 2.0 now and it looks a bit different.